# Updating values of a dictionary one by one with user's input in python

Tags: python

I would like to make a user updating the values from a dictionnary in python. I managed to write this code so far which is working :

```
myDict = {'NAME': '', 'PARENT': '', 'TEACHER': ''}

for k, v in myDict.items():
    v = input(
        'please enter a value for NAME, PARENT and TEACHER : ')
    myDict[k] = v

print(myDict)
```

The problem is that I would rather prefer to get a prompt for each keys like :

```
'Please enter value for NAME: '
'Please enter value for PARENT: '
'Please enter value for TEACHER: '
```

thank you!

Xzi.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just put `k` in the prompt.

There's also no need to use `items()` since you don't care about the old value. Just loop over the keys.

```
for k in myDict:
    v = input(f'Please enter a value for {k}: ')
    myDict[k] = v
```